# OpenCV python, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to create a live drowsiness detection program with OpenCV in python, but I keep getting this error. I have been researching this for the past hour but I cannot find a solution. I also looked at the code for a while, but I cannot seem to find out what is causing the issue. Why is this causing a problem?

**Before you say it is a duplicate, other posts of similar nature have not helped.**

Error:

```
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\FY22SciFair\Real-Time Drowsiness Detection OpenCV Python Source Code\drowsiness.py", line 65, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\games\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Code:

```
import json

jsonFile = open("VALUE.json", 'r+')
data = json.load(jsonFile)


def writeSave(save_data=1):
    data["VALUE"] = str(save_data)
    with open("VALUE.json", "w") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile)


from scipy.spatial import distance
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2


def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    A = distance.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = distance.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
    C = distance.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)
    return ear


thresh = 0.25
frame_check = 20
detect = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predict = dlib.shape_predictor(".\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")  # Dat file is the crux of the code

(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_68_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_68_IDXS["right_eye"]
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    subjects = detect(gray, 0)
    for subject in subjects:
        shape = predict(gray, subject)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
    # converting to NumPy Array
    leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
    rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
    leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
    rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
    ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
    leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
    rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    if ear < thresh:
        flag += 1
    print(flag)
    if flag >= frame_check:
        cv2.putText(frame, "****************ALERT!****************", (10, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "****************ALERT!****************", (10, 325),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        print("Drowsy")
    flag = 0
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

Comment: `cap.read()` is returning None into `frame`

Comment: Do you mean it isn't getting my camera feed? I tried switching the VideoCapture number but it gives me a similar error (https://pastebin.com/zgV7s4Q5).

Comment: I mean what I said. The value of `frame` is None. You should figure out why or decide what your code should do in that situation. If you have a question about whatever cv2 is you should ask that question instead.

Comment: How do I make it work correctly? I have tried putting if frame == None: break after the definition of frame, but It still does not work. Why is this?

Comment: because you *would* need to say `if frame is None:` -- `is` is for identity comparison, `==` is for value comparison. -- you **should** say `if not ret: break` instead because that thing is how `cap.read` tells you it can't read -- and you **should** `assert cap.isOpened()` once before even entering the loop. all of this is basic stuff for using VideoCapture, which is explained in all the other questions with answers, and in the documentation/examples.

Comment: do you even have a webcam attached to the same computer that runs this code? indication of CAP_MSMF at least tells me you run this on windows, so it's probably your own computer and not a remote computer like with google colab... maybe pycharm interferes somehow. run the code standalone, outside of pycharm, i.e. from a command prompt

Comment: I do have a webcam, and for some reason it used to work, but it started giving me this error (I didn't modify it or anything I'm not sure why)

Comment: when you say "Before you say it is a duplicate, other posts of similar nature have not helped.", you need to list those questions/answers you *did* find and explain precisely why each did not answer your question.

Comment: see if other processes run that might still access the camera. on windows, only one process at a time can access a webcam (usually). when in doubt, reboot the computer. [*have you tried turning it off and on again?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Comment: I tried using assert cap.isOpened() but it still gives me an error

Comment: as it should, when it can't open the video device. that's what an assertion does. -- then you need to find out _why_ the camera can't be opened. two options: it's not there, or it's already opened by something else.

Comment: just reset - still an error. How do I check the index of my webcam?

Comment: if you have one webcam, it'll be index 0. if you think there could be another one, trying index 1 can make sense. any other indices will make no sense unless you have enough cameras. -- try `apiPreference=cv.CAP_DSHOW` to VideoCapture. worth a try.

Comment: I still get an error. The camera is present and not being used, therefore it has to be another problem. The message says that the issue lies in this line:  https://pastebin.com/RjpCBWrP (The error message in the question says this too)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you know why it is doing this? I am pretty sure CJR's assessment that frame is None is correct, but why is this?

Comment: @CJR Frame is [[ 88 110 106]
  [ 88 110 106]
  [ 88 110 106]
  ...
  [173 179 191]
  [171 177 189]
  [171 178 188]]  (In one example)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The error seems to be line 51  `shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)` as it causes an error when I uncomment it.

Comment: don't assume that the frame is always valid or None in every iteration. your debugging skills need honing. the issue is indeed that frame is None. everything else is just a consequence of that.